# How to force react-map-gl Map to rerender on props change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mapbox-gl-js, react-map-gl

I am using the react-map-gl `Map` component in my project. I pass in via props `props.displayUploadedFiles`, an array of GeoJSON objects. I want to display these GeoJSON objects on my `Map` using react-map-gl's `Source` and `Layer` components. However, when I upload files, the only way to see the data from the files on the map is if I move/pan the map in order to force a re-render.

I would expect that I could use a hook to say "when this prop changes, change the Sources and Layers within my Map and display them." However, instead of displaying immediately, the hook does not seem to trigger until I pan the map.

I can confirm that the files are uploaded and in proper GeoJSON format, and that the props passed into the `Map` component are updating as the props update.

Here is an example of how the props are passed through:

```
// App.tsx
export default function App(): JSX.Element {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState<any[]>([]);
  const setFilesState = (filesUploaded: File[]) => {
    const jsons = kmlToGeoJson(filesUploaded);
    setFiles(jsons);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <MyMap displayUploadedFiles={files} ... />
      <MyFileUploader fileStateUpdater={setFilesState} />
    </>
  );
}

//MyMap.tsx
function MapboxMap(props: MapboxMapProps): JSX.Element {
  const geoJsons = useMemo(() => (props.displayUploadedFiles.map((file) => {
    const id = JSON.stringify(file.features);
    return (
      <Source key={id} type="geojson" data={file}>
        <Layer key={id} {...pointLayer} />
      </Source>
    );
  })), [JSON.stringify(props.displayUploadedFiles)]); // runs on upload once I move the map

  return (
    <Map mapboxAccessToken={mapboxToken} ...>
      {geoJsons}
      ...
    </Map>
  );
}

function MyMap(props: StyledMapProps): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <div id={sx.styledMap}>
      <MapboxMap ... displayUploadedFiles={props.displayUploadedFiles} />
      ...
  );
}

export default MyMap;
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47329381/markers-not-displaying-until-map-moved-slightly-or-clicked-in-react-map-gl) seems very similar to my problem, but for class-based instead of functional design. It indicates that I should use `useEffect()`. However, I could not get that to work--it had the same behavior I described above. The minimal example has `useMemo()` as I tried that as well.

The minimal example also shows the `useMemo()` dependency as `[JSON.stringify(props.displayUploadedFiles)]`, because I thought that just passing in the array might have been the problem, as the reference might not change even if the contents did, meaning it wouldn't re-render. However, this did not change the behavior.

I have also tried changing where `MyFileUploader` is located, such that the props are not passed from App.tsx, but rather the logic is contained within either `MyMap` or `MapboxMap`, but they don't change the behavior. In any situation, the props always update properly, but the hook that depends on it does not get called until I pan the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did figure out why the re-render wasn't being triggered properly by the `useEffect()` call as we would expect it to. However, I figured out a workaround for those interested.

in the `MapboxMap` component, I added this:

```
  const mapRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (mapRef?.current) {
      mapRef.current.zoomTo(mapRef.current.getZoom());
    }
  }, [props.displayUploadedFiles]);
```

It goes into the underlying mapbox-gl map object and, whenever more files are updated, it "zooms in" to the current zoom level. This has the effect of if I were to pan the map manually, but automates it. It forces the map to re-render and makes it so the user can't perceive the viewport change.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `useEffect` to watch for changes in the prop and trigger the update of the map layers. You can also use the `useMemo` hook to memoize the `geoJsons` array, for performance.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';
import { Map, Source, Layer } from 'react-map-gl';

function MapboxMap(props) {
  const geoJsons = useMemo(() => (
    props.displayUploadedFiles.map((file) => {
      const id = JSON.stringify(file.features);
      return (
        <Source key={id} type="geojson" data={file}>
          <Layer key={id} {...pointLayer} />
        </Source>
      );
    })
  ), [props.displayUploadedFiles]);

  // Use useEffect to trigger the map update when props change
  useEffect(() => {
    // Force a map update when the displayUploadedFiles prop changes
    // This will re-render the map layers immediately
    // You may also need to handle map updates here if required
  }, [props.displayUploadedFiles]);

  return (
    <Map mapboxAccessToken={mapboxToken} ...>
      {geoJsons}
      {/* ... */}
    </Map>
  );
}

export default MyMap;
```

this should now update immediately when the `displayUploadedFiles` prop changes, without the need to pan the map.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Unfortunately, this still has the same behavior as before. It seems that, even though I can confirm the prop changed in `MapboxMap` via console.log, the `useEffect()` hook doesn't get called when the prop changes, but only after I pan the map.